# how to create a policy in Polly to support http response retry-after header

Tags: c#, polly

I am trying to create a `Polly` policy to support  `http response retry-after header`

```
 var retryAfterPolicy = Policy
               .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r?.Headers?.RetryAfter != null)
               .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: retryAttemptsBeforeBreaking,
                                    sleepDurationProvider: (count, response, context) => GetServerWaitDuration(response)
                );
```

Above code gives me error,

> 'PolicyBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WaitAndRetryAsync' and the best extension method overload 'RetrySyntaxAsync.WaitAndRetryAsync(PolicyBuilder, int, Func)' requires a receiver of type 'PolicyBuilder'

How to support this and I have to wrap this with other policy like `circuitBreakerPolicy` as well?

Comment: It's as if you got muddled up and used Json parameters used, eg in Python style: `retryCount: retryAttemptsBeforeBreaking` in your C#

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I use

```
Policy
.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r =>
   r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests && r.Headers.RetryAfter != null)
.WaitAndRetryAsync(3, 
   sleepDurationProvider: (_, result, _) => result.Result.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta.Value,
   onRetryAsync: async (_, _, _, _) => { })
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. Minor mod to your onretryAsync handler to avoid a roslynator warning about not using await:
onRetryAsync: async (_, _, _, _) => await Task.CompletedTask

Answer (score 3):

Update your code like below, it should work

```
var retryAfterPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r?.Headers?.RetryAfter != null)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        3, 
        i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), 
        (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
            {
                _logger.LogCritical($"Request failed with {result.Result.StatusCode}. Waiting {timeSpan} before next retry. Retry attempt {retryCount}");
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. It's works, but how to calculate time from retry-after?

Comment: Covered in the Polly documentation: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retryafter-when-the-response-specifies-how-long-to-wait